# Алгоритм ротации и перемещения матрицы (изображения)

Tags: матрицы, алгоритм

В общем есть некая матрица, вида:

```
[r,g,b,a],[r,g,b,a],[r,g,b,a],[r,g,b,a],[r,g,b,a]
[r,g,b,a],[r,g,b,a],[r,g,b,a],[r,g,b,a],[r,g,b,a]
[r,g,b,a],[r,g,b,a],[r,g,b,a],[r,g,b,a],[r,g,b,a]
[r,g,b,a],[r,g,b,a],[r,g,b,a],[r,g,b,a],[r,g,b,a]
[r,g,b,a],[r,g,b,a],[r,g,b,a],[r,g,b,a],[r,g,b,a]
```

Есть еще много много матриц такого же вида, только другого размера.

По сути всё это будет матрицами изображений.

Первая задача - это повернуть мартицу на определенный градус (вики пишет: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_matrix_transposition , http://eab.abime.net/coders-general/29492-c-image-rotation-algorithm-problem.html )

Вторая задача - это одну матрицу размером, например, 10х10 вставить в матрицу размером 100х100, причем начать с 50 строки 50 столбца (тоже для примера).

Буду рад ссылкам на источники.

Comment: По поводу второй задачи, не понял.. Ну вот вставил к примеру 10х10 в 100х100 начиная с 50х50, а все значения по бокам что нулями забивать чтоли?

Comment: @qpaycm допустим я копирую изображение 10х10 на изображение 100х100, вот как это сделать? А если еще и альфа канал нужно сохранить?

Comment: Не знаю, какой ответ лучше выбрать, т.к. все по сути правильные. Что делать?

Comment: @lampa, берём ячейку с которой начинается наложение(50х50) и от неё двигаемся заменяя значения все кроме альфа-канала(оно?). Для этого можно применить формулу линейной трансформации.

Comment: @qpaycm я уже всё сделал, что хотел) Я просто не знаю, какой ответ выбрать решением, т.к. каждый пригодился.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На счет второй задачи, то как я лично думаю (теорий на эту тему не знаю):

К примеру были ячейки: Q = (200, 200, 100, 50) и W = (100, 100, 150, 50) // максимальное число 255

(R G B):

```
K1 = 200/256; // = 0.78125
K2 = 100/256; // = 0.390625 
Q = (200 * K1, 100 *K1, 50*K1) // = (156.25, 78.125, 39.0625)
W = (100 * K2, 150 *K2, 50*K2) // = (39.0625, 58.59375, 19.53125)
// возьмем средний цвет - это для сложение с предыдущим цветом
// если надо вставлять, можно брать просто второй цвет
R[] = (Q[] + W[])/2 // (97.65625, 68,359375, 29,296875)
// дальше компенсируем цвета по альфа, обратное действие что делали вначале
// при этом берется альфа того, куда встраиваем
R[] *= 256 / 200 // (125, 87.5, 37,5)
```

Если просто вставить цвет, без сложений, то:

```
// Умножаем на старую прозрачность, делим на новую прозрачность
R[] = W[] * W[A] / Q[A]
```

Comment: да, на счет сохранения альфа канала это походу то, что нужно!

Answer (score 4):

[image: rotation]
​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

[ссылка на источник](https://web.archive.org/web/20201113214817/https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/opengl/CG_BasicsTheory.html)

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужно смотреть в сторону матричных преобразований. т.е есть специальные матрицы. например:

из вики

- [Матрица поворота](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0)
- [Матрица перехода](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0) (в этой статье так же описаны матрицы: масштабирования, поворота и перемещения )